# Support of principal divisor and exceptional locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Assume we have a birational morphism between smooth varieties $\phi : X \longrightarrow Y$. Let $f$ be a non-zero rational function of $X$, and $E$ be the exceptional locus of $\phi$. I think we should have $\text{supp}(\text{div(f)}) \not\subset E$, but I don't find any argument.
Otherwise, maybe we should look at the push-forward, and then we could deduce that $\text{Nm}_{K(X)/K(Y)}(f) \in K^{\times}$ where $K$ is the field of definition of our varieties. Then, I'm tempted to say that we should have $f \in K^\times$.
What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the support of the divisor associated to $f$ on $X$ is contained in the exceptional locus, that means the support of the divisor associated to $f$ on $Y$ is contained inside a subset of codimension at least two. But this implies that the divisor associated to $f$ on $Y$ is trivial: the vanishing locus of a function on a normal variety is pure codimension one.

$\operatorname{div} f=0$ does not quite force $f\in K^\times$ without more assumptions: $x/(x-1)$ is a function with trivial divisor on $\Bbb A^1\setminus \{0,1\}$. You'll need at least completeness to ensure that, plus maybe some algebraically closedness hypotheses on the base field.

Comment: When you say the divisor associated to $f$ on $Y$, do you mean $f_*(div(f))$ ? In that case, of course the push-forward of $div(f) $ is zero, but I don't understand why $div(f) =0$ in that case ? (we don't have finiteness hypothesis on $f$ by the way).

Comment: $\phi$ is birational, so it identifies $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$. If $div_Y(f)$ contains any points outside $\phi(E)$, then $div_X(f)=\phi^{-1}(div_Y(f))$ would not be contained in $E$.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you !